# Angularjs - How to change background color using radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, ng-class

On my page, I have dynamically created radio buttons. I want to change wrapper background color when radio button is selected.

following is my code

```
<section ng-repeat="list in myList">
  <div class="radioWrapper">
    <input type="radio" name="{{list.category}}" ng-model="list.name">
    <label>{{list.name}} </label>
   </div>
</section>
```

I want to add "selectedRadioBg" class at the radioWrapper when each radio is selected.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

```
<section ng-repeat="list in myList">
  <div ng-class="myClass">
    <input type="radio" name="{{list.category}}" ng-model="list.name">
    <label>{{list.name}} </label>
   </div>
</section>

// in controller/link

if($scope.list.name){
  $scope.myClass = {background: #B250C2};
}
```

See: [**ngClass**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

#### What's happening

You got a ngModel `list.name` on your radio button. If the radio is checked, it's value evaluates to `true`

You watch for $scope.list.name to be true, and if so, set an object named `myClass` to your scope, which contains the styles. This object is bound to your markup:

`<div ng-class="myClass">`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `ng-class` directive. Documentation can be found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

This directive allows you to conditionally apply a class based on an expression, in this case the radio button selection.

So, using your example, you can have the following code:

```
<div class="radioWrapper" ng-class="{'selectedRadioBg': list.name}>
    <input type="radio" name="{{list.category}}" ng-model="list.name">
    <label>{{list.name}} </label>
</div>
```

`list.name` acts as a truthy / falsy expression here.

Comment: I tried this code. But the issue was 'selectedRadioBg' class applied to the wrapper div before the user clicks on the radio button. Then I tried following code

<div class="radioWrapper" ng-class="{'selectedRadioBg': list.name == list.value}>

    <input type="radio" name="{{list.category}}" ng-model="list.name" value="{{list.value}}">

    <label>{{list.name}} </label>

</div>

Comment: In this code I want to remove selectedRadioBg class when user unchecked the radio button. Even user unchecked the radio still the selectedRadioBg class remain in the wrapper div

Comment: I have a feeling that there is more than meets the eye - Since you are using radio buttons, I assume there is more than one of them - can you create a plunkr or fiddle that has the complete code so that it is easier to understand the issue... If not, then I hope you get the gist of the solution - use `ng-class` to conditionally apply styling and that should help you out..

Answer (score 0):

```
<section ng-repeat="list in myList">
    <div class="radioWrapper" ng-class="{'selectedRadioBg': list.name}>
        <input type="radio" name="{{list.category}}" ng-model="list.name">
        <label>{{list.name}} </label>
    </div>
</section>
```

Replace with

```
<section ng-repeat="list in myList">
    <div class="radioWrapper" style="background: {{list.name}} none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
        <input type="radio" name="{{list.category}}" ng-model="list.model">
        <label>{{list.name}} </label>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Do not put your list.name in ng-model directive.